# Actionscript - Call subclass constructor from base class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

I want to create an instance of a subclass from inside a static superclass method. Here is an example:

```
class Base
{
    public static function createSubclassInstance()
    {
        //What do I do here?
        return new this.getSubclassType();
    }
}

class Sub extends Base
{
}
```

I want to create a new `Sub` instance by calling:

```
var s:Sub = Sub.createSubclassInstance();
```

Comment: I think you can't extend static methods.

Comment: I am a bit confused.  You are creating a `Sub` instance, why not just instantiate it like you would normally?

Comment: sberry2A: There is other functionality that I want to wrap inside the createSubclassInstance() which is irrelevant to the question

Comment: Looks like M28 is right, can't extend static methods

Comment: I'd really, **really**! like to know why you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[static properties aren't inherited](http://wonderfl.net/c/lLor)